# What does "of" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "of" mean in this context? Can I subtstitue it for "from?"

> Mo Salah **of** Liverpool made a loose pass, allowing Mbappe to link with Messi scoring and equalising goal.

Comment: Yes, Salah is from Liverpool now, but *of* is more general here = connected to Liverpool.  *From* could be taken literally to mean originally born there, while *of* means associated with that locale more loosely.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: this isn't about the place but the team.

Comment: @YosefBaskin So there is no difference betwewn **of** and **from** in this context, isn't there? I can say "Salah **from** Liverpool made a loose pas..."

Answer (score 3):

Here "of Liverpool" means "belonging to the Liverpool team". You could substitute "from", but it would be less idiomatic.

Comment: Can you explain why "from" is less idiomatic in that sentence?

Comment: @Nyambek - 'from' is less idiomatic because we normally use 'from _a place_' to say that someone is a native of that place. Also sports journalism has conventions and one of them that you write e.g. 'Jones **of** Manchester City' in a story about a match. Not 'from'.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that **of Liverpool** means that Salah is **on the Liverpool team**. You could also say:

> Liverpool's Mo Salah made a loose pass...

I disagree that **from** is a permissible substitution. To me, **from** pertains to Mo Salah, not to the team. It says that Mo Salah lives/was born in Liverpool, not that he's on the Liverpool team.

Also, the rest of your sentence doesn't really make any sense, FYI.

> ... allowing Mbappe to link with Messi scoring and equalising goal.

Maybe something like:

> ... allowing Mbappe to pass to Messi, who scored and tied the game.